# Having difficulties to apply split function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to complete a code challenge while I'm learning JS, and I got stuck in the word split in pyramid shape.

The challenge it's checking which word has lower length, store the shortest word in a variable and then printing the word in a pyramid style:

```
const wordList = [
    'wordA',
    'wordAB',
    'wordABC'
];
```

Output should be:

```
w
wo
wor
word
wordA
The shortest word it's "wordA"
```

here it's my code

```
let shortestWord;

function findShortest(arrList) {
  return arrList.reduce( function(shortest, current) {
    return (shortest=='' || current.length < shortest.length) ? current : shortest;
  }, '');
};

shortestWord = findShortest(wordList);

console.log(shortestWord.split);
console.log("\nThe shortest word it's "" + shortestWord + """);
```

The error I got was `[Function: split]`
I have no idea how to solve this...

Comment: do you have only strings in the array or different types?

Comment: You need to call the function `split()` (and add any necessary arguments). That's not an error.

Comment: I only have strings in the array yes

Comment: then you need no check for type.

Comment: thanks, will remove the check type ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```js
const wordList = [
  'wordA',
  'wordAB',
  'wordABC',
];
let hit = null;
wordList.forEach((word) => {
  if (hit == null || word.length < hit.length) {
    hit = word;
  }
});
const splittedHit = hit.split('');
let splitOutput = '';
splittedHit.forEach(c => {
  splitOutput += c;
  console.log(splitOutput);
});
console.log(`Shortest word is: ${hit}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort words based on length, take the first element, loop through it add substring to `final` from 0 to i on each iteration

```js
const wordList = ['wordAB','wordA','wordABC'];
let final = ''
let shortest = wordList.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)[0]

for (let i = 1; i < shortest.length; i++) {
  final += shortest.substring(0, i) + '\n'
}

console.log(final.trim())
console.log("The shortest word it's " + shortest);
```